# Error with Image Slide plug-in/ s3slider in WP

Tags: plugins, php, jquery

I'm using Wordpress Version 2.8 *(Can't upgrade where I work)*; and I used 'Emerald Stretch' theme as the basic bone structure of what I'm developing. *(Which ultimately will be a responsive wordpress theme, using css3 media queries, and a rotating jquery banner underneath the header and ideally I'd be able to use this one)*

The first thing is the version I'm using; I know - I don't have an option so if there could be different responses that'd be awesome.

I want to implement a slide show similar to; http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/demonstration.html at Example #2 in the link.

So, I found a *serie3* slider plug-in *(The plug-in homepage says it's WP 2.0.2 compatible)* I was going to use; after installing it and going to it's menu to upload my first image - I get the below error;

"**Warning : The permissions to the directory /data/24/1/0/139/1815302/user/1967139/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/s3slider-plugin/files/ are invalid. Set them to 777 to be able to upload files. "**

The plug-in homepage: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/s3slider-plugin/

How can I fix this - so that it will work? ..and if I can't, any suggestions on as to where I can began implementing it's code from scratch? I began trying to implement it in header.php but after previewing it wouldn't render there?

***What I have currently is located at; www.o s m p r o d u c t i o n.com***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is telling you that you need to chmod (the permissions) the folder to 777 via your ftp client. This will enable the plugin to read, write and execute to the folder on the server.

Comment: Rad! Thanks for the response; when I'm back at work I'll see how it goes.

Comment: Not a problem. Let me know how it goes. :)

Comment: So, I'm now able to work with the plug-in via the WP control panel; but it won't activate on my site.

Comment: Most plugins come with a read me file. You may have to use a shortcode in the page editor that the slider is to show on or a key code of sorts in your theme.

Comment: Sorry for the double post. I forgot enter posts the comment. lol Addons possibly like this slider will not show until you put the codes in. Usually you can find the info on the plugin's website or generally in their readme file.